# How to prevent Taskbar button disappearing when form is hidden

Tags: delphi

How to prevent Taskbar button disappearing when the only form of application is hidden?

My application has one  always on top  form,  but sometimes I need to hide it,  but still keep Taskbar button visible.  Taskbar button is used to control the product.

Comment: `ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE)` leaves the Taskbar button visible. at least in XP. but "Taskbar button is used to control the product": what are you expecting to happen when the user clicks the Taskbar button?

Comment: @kobik - That probably depends on MainFormOnTaskBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taskbar buttons are not shown for hidden windows. So, if the taskbar button is associated with your main form's window, and you hide that form, then the taskbar button will be hidden.

So, I guess the easiest thing to do would be to stop hiding the main form. Use `Application.Minimize`, or `WindowState := wsMinimized` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Or if you wanna avoid minimization/maximization effects by minimizing/maximizing form use Alpha transparency and set it to 0 (fully transparent) instead.
This way you hide the window from users sight, but from the OS side the window is still visible so it will maintain its Taskbar button.

Comment: What happens when you click on that fully transparent window?

Comment: As far as I know form with alpha transparency set to 0 doesen't registers clicks but I'm not sure of that. Since I don't have access to my development machine I can't test this now.

Comment: I have also checked this now both in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE3 and it works in both of them. But now when I ihink about this more I do remember that one of the older versions of Delphi did still detect the mose cicks even if Alpha Transparency was set to 0.

Comment: This sounds a good option, we already use transparency a lot.
 However what are limits of DISPLAY DRIVER/ADAPTER; is it possible that e.g. in older XP machine its not working

Comment: @Tom - Layered windows are [available since W2K](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx). Of course I cannot comment on specific display problems on a particular box.

Comment: Nice solution. But has an issue with taskbar responsiveness. If I minimize the secondary form, it goes down to the corner of the screen, instead of the taskbar icon.  Also clicking the taskbar icon while visible doesn't minimize it as desired.